# Find the indicated set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning, cardinals

[image]

Can someone confirm this?

Sorry if it looks messy, I don't know where to find the math notations.

** x represents the cartesian product

P({1,2}) x P({3})

= {{1},{2},{1,2},{}} x {{},{3}}

= {{{1},{3}},{{2},{3}},{{1,2},{3}}}

I first calculate the power set of each set and then find the cartesian product.

This is what I could think of in terms of approaching this question; however i'm not very confident with my answer.

Comment: Why don't you include anything crossed with the empty set.   There should be 8 elements and you only list three.  You reasoning seems right otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct.  You did not expand the Cartesian product correctly.  The output of the product is a set of ordered pairs, while you show a set of two element sets.  You have four choices for the first element and two for the second, so should have eight elements in all.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming incorrectly ordered pairs involving the empty set aren't allowable.  As 4 pairs have the empty set to the right, two have it to the left, and one is a pair of empty sets, that removes 5 of the eight pairs.

Comment: @fleablood:  good point.  C. L.: you should include pairs that have the empty set as a member.  The empty set is a fine set and a fine element in ordered pairs.  It was correct to include it as an element in the power set, which you did.

Comment: Should the ordered pairs involving the empty set be included in the cartesian product? If so, would {{1}, {}} be correct as being one of the cartesian product?

Comment: @C.L:  yes, they should.  That is an example of one of the missing ones.  You are still showing it as a set, which does not enforce the order.  I suspect you use the [Kuratowski definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition) of ordered pairs, so you need to make yours look like that.

Comment: Yes, they should.  As "things" the empty set(s) are perfectly valid and can be placed in ordered pairs.

Comment: And I agree that ordered pair notation such as ({1,2}, {}) would be a lot easier to read.  And maybe even clearer to comprehend.

Comment: So again:  there should be 8 not 3 ordered pairs.  I trust you can figure what they are.  The five you left out all involved the empty set.